# Mandelbrot's algorithm not giving the desired result without using complex numbers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, mandelbrot

when i use the following algorithm for using the mandelbrot algorithm i get the a image similar to the image i want but it looks more like an outline of the final image and when i use the algorithm with complex numbers it gives a proper sharp image

the code is written in c++

```
//pseudocode 
//z=x+yi    //x=0,y=0
//c=x0+y0i  //x=scaled(px),y=scaled(py)
//do
//z2=x2+(2*xy)i-y2
//z=z2+c   //z=x2-y2+x0+(2*xy+y0)i
//x=x2-y2+x0   //y=2*xy+y0
//x2=x*x       //y2=y*y
//if(sqrt(x2+y2)<2 )
// break
//iteration++
//while( iteration<max_iteration)
```

- 

```
//code without complex numbers
int mandelbrot::_test_num_iteration( double px, double py ) {
double x0{ scale_x( px ) }, x{ 0 };
double y0{ scale_y( py ) }, y{ 0 };
double x2{ 0 }, y2{ 0 };
//z=x+iy        c=x0+iy0
int iteration{ 0 };
while (iteration < max_iteration) {         //for instance max_iteration=1000
    x2 = x * x;             y2 = y * y;
    x = x2  + x0 - y2;      y = 2 * x * y + y0;
    x2 = (x * x);           y2 = (y * y);
    if (sqrt(( x2 + y2 )) > 2)   
        break;
    iteration++;
}
return iteration;
}
```

- 

```
 //code with complex numbers
    int mandelbrot::get_iteration( double px, double py) {
    //x+iy=z
    //z2=x2+(2*xyi)-y2
    //c=x0+iy0
    //x0&y0=scaled x and y coordinates
    double x{ scale_x( px ) };
    double y{ scale_y( py ) };
    complex::complex_numbers z;
    complex::complex_numbers c{ x,y };
    int iteration{ 0 };
    while (iteration < max_iteration) {
        z = z * z + c;
        if (mod( z ) > 2)   //mod is a function which returns sqrt(x2+y2)
            break;
        iteration++;
    }

    return iteration;
    }
```

Comment: what is `complex` exactly ? There must be differences in the codes, without seeing the complete code one cannot tell what difference taht is. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: His name was Mandelbrot.

Comment: Don't compare `sqrt(x2 + y2) > 2` as `sqrt()` is horribly slow. You can square both sides giving you `x2 + y2 > 4` for a much faster test. Similar for complex numbers use `norm(z) > 4`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 complex is a custom namespace where i created a c++ class named complex_numbers. Its the same as the complex header class just a bit optimised to do certain tasks and contains some custom functions those functions are exactly what the name suggests like mod for modulus of a complex number. I am really sorry to cause that confusion.

Comment: It is impossible to calculate a Mandelbrot without complex numbers (or at least emulating the behavior of complex numbers -> i^2 = -1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not calculating both new values from the old values.
Here,

```
x = x2  + x0 - y2;      y = 2 * x * y + y0;
```

you're using the new `x` for the new `y`.
You need a couple of variables for temporary storage of the updated values.

```
double new_x = x2 - y2 + x0;      
double new_y = 2 * x * y + y0;
x = new_x;
y = new_y;
```

Comment: Or just compute y befor x.

Comment: ohkk my bad thanks for pointing it out i think instead of creating 2 variables we can create one and then we can continue in 2 steps and 1 temporary variable   
`double new_x = x2 - y2 + x0;`
`y = 2 * x * y + y0;`
`x = new_x;`

Answer (score 2):

One error is in this block:

```
    x2 = x * x;             y2 = y * y;
    x = x2  + x0 - y2;      y = 2 * x * y + y0;
```

You try to implement `z*z+c`. However, in the second line you change the real part of "z" to the square of the real part minus the imaginary part plus the constant.  At this time, the real part of z has been updated.  Next you update y (imaginary part with the updated real part).  Oops.

I would go through line by line and check that your implementation of the complex number operations really do what they are supposed to do.  Use some `cout <<` statements if you do not know how to use the debugger.

Edit: removed incorrect `sqrt(x2+y2)` comment.

Comment: @molbdnilo Overlooked that line.  Thanks for pointing out.